# Apache and passenger setup virtualhost restart failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have installed passenger on my Ubuntu 10.x server and I am running Apache2. I have followed the instruction "I think" pretty well. After setting up my virtual host and trying to restart I am getting a failed to start apache error because Documentroot takes one argument. I have the document root set is the thing so I am wondering if you guys could offer some suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong.

I have all my virtual hosts in separate files by domain name, so the directory structure on the server is something like this

/etc/apache2/sites-available/dev.mydomain.com
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.mydomain.com

both files have the following in them but restarting apache only fails when I put the vhost info in the enabled file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dev.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /home/myfolder/dev/vb/public    # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
  <Directory /home/myfolder/dev/vb/public>
     AllowOverride all              # <-- relax Apache security settings
     Options -MultiViews            # <-- MultiViews must be turned off
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: BTW here is the error I get when restarting apache http://grab.by/7LS7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments in httpd.conf must go on their own line.

Answer (score 2):

have you given before defining VirtualHost

NameVirtualHost *:80

if this given remove those commented line after document root and try